# Does CodeModel support importing classes from unspecified packages?

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

I want to generate a file containing a reference to a class without knowing which package it actually comes from.

E.g. the user supplies

```
import foo.*
import blah.*

Button("press me")
```

and I need to generate

```
import foo.*;
import blah.*;

public class MyWindow extends Window {
    public MyWindow() {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setLabel("press me");
    }
}
```

The class `Button` can be in either package. Is this sort of scenario supported by CodeModel? The examples at [CodeModel help needed for right-hand singleton.getinstance() assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851937/codemodel-help-needed-for-right-hand-singleton-getinstance-assignment) and [A Java API to generate Java source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121324/a-java-api-to-generate-java-source-files) specify complete package names for classes, and a look at the [JavaDoc](http://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/) didn't help.

Comment: may be this helps

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851937/codemodel-help-needed-for-right-hand-singleton-getinstance-assignment