# generating import using Jcodemodel

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven-3

I am trying to generate java code using Jcodemodel.

1. How to generate required import statements using Jcodemodel?
2. How to automatically generate the implementation of interface methods when a class implements the interface?

   eg:

   ```
   interface Act {

      void act();

   }
   ```

   using Jcodemodel, how to generate the interface method in implementation class? whether do I need to write method using JMethod? Is there any other way to auto generate the implementation methods?
3. How to generate required imports for a class?

Kindly,guide me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851937/codemodel-help-needed-for-right-hand-singleton-getinstance-assignment contains an example for imports

Answer (score 2):

You should use the method

```
JClass importedClass= codeModel.ref("example.com.impl.MyClass");
```

And make sure `example.com.impl.MyClass` is in your classpath.
In the generated java source, the `import example.com.impl.MyClass` statement will be automatically added for you.